# Drupal unable to create files on /var/www/html/drupal directory

Tags: file-permissions, webserver, apache-http-server, drupal

I am trying to install drupal 7.18 in my Fedora 14 machine . I put the drupal filess in `/var/www/html/drupal` directory and set `chmod 7777 -R drupal` permission. But when I tried to install drupal it shows errors like :

> File system    The directory sites/default/files does not exist. An
>   automated attempt to create this directory failed, possibly due to a
>   permissions problem. To proceed with the installation, either create
>   the directory and modify its permissions manually or ensure that the
>   installer has the permissions to create it automatically. For more
>   information, see INSTALL.txt or the online handbook.
>
> Settings file The settings file does not exist. The Drupal installer
>   requires that you create a settings file as part of the installation
>   process. Copy the ./sites/default/default.settings.php file to
>   ./sites/default/settings.php. More details about installing Drupal are
>   available in INSTALL.txt.

What is the issue there?? I am newbie to Linux.

Comment: Are you sure `drupal` is the name of your web server's user? Not `www-data` or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check that who is the owner of files. If it is user different with `www-data` you should change it to that user by doing:

```
$ cd /var/www && chown -R www-data:www-data html
```

This will take all files and change its owner and owner group to `www-data`.

That's maybe not intuitive, but during Drupal installation you should do some manual work. The error you receive clearly states what you should do.

First confirm that you have directory `/var/www/html/drupal/sites/default/files`. If doesn't exist you should create it by doing:

```
$ mkdir /var/www/html/drupal/sites/default/files
```

Secondly copy settings template to another file by doing:

```
$ cp /var/www/html/drupal/sites/default/default.settings.php /var/www/html/drupal/sites/default/settings.php
```

This should be pretty much enough. If there will be any further error messages. Simply follow what they ask you to do...

Answer (score 1):

Single Drupal site setup:

**To create the files folder:**

```
cd /var/www/[website] [anyway it is the path to your web directory]

sudo mkdir sites/default/files && sudo chmod -R 777 files && sudo chown -R www-data:www-data files [or sudo chown -R apache:apache files]
```

**To create the settings.php**

```
cd /var/www/[website] [anyway it is the path to your web directory]

sudo cp sites/default/default.settings.php sites/default/settings.php

sudo chmod -R 755 settings.php
```

Once you finished the installation, you need to do:

```
sudo chmod 644 settings.php
```

or whatever you want to prevent write from other users.